# Subdomain setup in apache not working, suspected conflict

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, httpd.conf

I've setup the following in my virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost app.pdf-edelivery.com>
ServerName app.pdf-edelivery.com
DocumentRoot /home/pdfedelivery/public_html/site
<Directory "/home/pdfedelivery/public_html/site/">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The premise is that I want to redirect app.pdf-edelivery.com to the `site/` folder.
Here's the issue i'm facing. I think there is some sort of conflict. If you `ping app.pdf-edelivery.com` it resolves to the correct IP address of my server.

About 6 records above that record (in the httpd.conf file) there is this record:

```
<VirtualHost pdf-edelivery.net>
DocumentRoot /home/pdfedelivery/public_html
<Directory "/home/pdfedelivery/public_html">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerAlias www.pdf-edelivery.net pdf-edelivery.net www.pdf-edelivery.com pdf-edelivery.com www.pdfedelivery.com pdfedelivery.com www.pdfedelivery.net pdfedelivery.net www.pdfedelivery.com.au pdfedelivery.com.au
</VirtualHost>
```

Which I am concerned is somehow conflicting with the above record. No matter how many times I restart apache, I can't get app.pdf-edelivery.com to go to the correct site (which you can currently see at pdf-edelivery.com/site/)

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `<VirtualHost ... >` statements to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

which will have apache respond to incoming name based virtual hosts on post 80 for all available IP addresses.

Check that you have a `NameVirtualHost *` (or similar) directive too

[NamevirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) Documentation

[VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) Documentation

[Name based](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) virtual hosting

Answer (score 0):

You should try this syntax :

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80> # where xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP you want Apache listen to.
ServerName pdf-edelivery.net
ServerAlias www.pdf-edelivery.net pdf-edelivery.net www.pdf-edelivery.com pdf-edelivery.com www.pdfedelivery.com pdfedelivery.com www.pdfedelivery.net pdfedelivery.net www.pdfedelivery.com.au pdfedelivery.com.au
DocumentRoot /home/pdfedelivery/public_html
<Directory "/home/pdfedelivery/public_html">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```